# JSF 2 ui:repeat: group every n items inside a div

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat

Given a collection that I want to arrange on a page like this:

```xhtml
<!-- Group 0 -->
<div style="float:left;">
    <div><!-- Item 0 --></div>
    <div><!-- Item 1 --></div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div><! -- Item n - 1 --></div>
</div>
<!-- Group 1 -->
<div style="float:left;">
    <div><!-- Item n     --></div>
    <div><!-- Item n + 1 --></div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div><! -- Item 2n - 1 --></div>
</div>

<!-- ... -->

<!-- Group g -->
    <div><!-- Item gn     --></div>
    <div><!-- Item gn + 1 --></div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div><! -- Item (g + 1)n - 1 --></div>
</div>
```

Is there some sort of trick I can use to do this inside a ui:repeat or by some other technique, *preferably* other than creating a custom component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the current loop round by the `varStatus` attribute and print the intermediary `</div><div style="float: left;">` whenever necessary.

E.g. every 3 items:

```html
<div style="float: left;">
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        <h:outputText value="&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div style='float: left;'&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{not loop.first and loop.index % 3 == 0}" />
        <div>#{item}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

Note that it's not possible to wrap this as plain HTML inside a `<h:panelGroup>`, because it would result in non-wellformed XML, hence the `<h:outputText escape="false">` with them as XML entities.

---

**Update** as per the comments, here's an alternate approach having the `<div>`s definied only once which is probably less confusing:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <h:outputText value="&lt;div style='float: left;'&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{loop.index % 3 == 0}" />
    <div>#{item}</div>
    <h:outputText value="&lt;/div&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{loop.last or (loop.index + 1) % 3 == 0}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Did you notice the `&lt;/div&gt;` in the output text? This closes the group. I count an even number of opening and closing divs tags, not an odd number.

Comment: Yes, I can see what you have done, which is why I took a good, long look at it and haven't edited yet. It's clever. Problem is, you need to open the first group.

Comment: Ah, the list can possibly be empty? Wrap all in `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">` then. Put it if necessary all in a composite to hide all the verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

If possible I would break collection on the server side:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{groups}" var="group">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <ui:repeat value="#{group.items}" var="item">
      <div>#{item.content}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
  </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

another option could be (haven't tested, not sure about size behaviour in particular):

```
<ui:repeat value="#{items}" var="group" varStatus="status" step="n">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <ui:repeat value="#{items}" var="item" offset="#{status.index}" size="#{status.index + n}">
      <div>#{item.content}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
  </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

EDIT: the second version has been replaced

Comment: +1 for your first solution because this would work and I thought of something similar a few minutes ago. My plan was to use a custom function to apply the grouping. I'm not sure your second solution would work, though. At the very least, any IDE will hate it.

Comment: The latter works in JSP only, not in Facelets, because it's syntactically invalid XML. But in JSP you don't have `<ui:xxx>` tags, only a `<c:forEach>` and `<c:if>`.

Comment: Your updated second example doesn't result in the desired HTML output.

Comment: Used another approach. Should be okay now.

Comment: This doesn't work if the list has size%n!=0 items. The `size` of the nested loop would then be bigger than actual remaining size.

Comment: Could be, but the question suggests size % n == 0. It's easy to adapt the code though.

Comment: I've used the second solution, works like charm, just in the second ui:repeat, the size must be n : size="n"