# JSF/XHTML/CSS 'tableview' of divs

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I am currently trying to iterate over a list which will generate a `<div>(...)</div>` for each value. These divs will be represented as 'blocks' (as shown in the image below). Problem is, I need them to align as in a row (so the new row starts at the lowest point of the previous).

[image]

This would be no problem when using a container div per row, like so:

```
<div>
    <div>(...)</div>
    <div>(...)</div>
    <div>(...)</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>(...)</div>
    <div>(...)</div>
    <div>(...)</div>
</div>
```

Though I would prefer not to use container divs, as I would need to use certain logic inside my `<ui:repeat>(...)</ui:repeat>` to add `</div><div>` on every third entry.

I'm posting this under JSF too, because I'm hoping that **JSF** (or **PrimeFaces** or **Tomahawk**) has an appropriate solution. Though, if **a simple CSS-trick** would suffice, that would be perfect.

Hopefully you'll be able to help me out with this one.

**Note:** a solution using tables won't help me, as I would face the same issue using `<tr>(...)</tr>` as with my described container div above.

Comment: is changing outer divs to span an option?

Comment: Is there a semantic reason to not use tables? This is easily possible with the combination `<h:panelGrid>` and `<c:forEach>`. Otherwise you really can't nicely go around a container div to represent a row.

Comment: Unbelievable how easy this was and that I completely forgot about `<h:panelGrid>`. This was indeed the tag I've been searching for. I would accept this as the answer if not posted as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a semantic reason to not use tables? This is easily possible with the combination `<h:panelGrid>` and `<c:forEach>`.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:panelGroup>#{item}</h:panelGroup>
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

It works that way because `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time and effectively generates physically multiple `<h:panelGroup>` components so that they properly end up each as a cell of the `<h:panelGrid>`. It wouldn't have worked when using `<ui:repeat>`, because that runs during view render time only and effectively ends up as a single cell of the `<h:panelGrid>` during view build time.

If there's a strong and valid semantic reason to not use tables, then you really can't nicely go around a container `<div>` to represent a row.

```
<div>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.items}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        <h:outputText value="&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div&gt;" escape="false" rendered="#{not loop.first and loop.index % 3 == 0}" />
        <div>#{item}</div>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)
- [JSF 2 ui:repeat: group every n items inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481742/jsf-2-uirepeat-group-every-n-items-inside-a-div)